# Bootstrap 4 SASS Table-Primary class not picking up changed Primary color?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I'm still learning BS4 and SASS but I'm not understanding why setting my primary color is not being picked up.

I created a customer variables file and set the color of `$blue` that I want. This is all I have in my `_custom-variables.scss` file.

```
$blue: #0078D2;
$light: #F7F7F7;
```

Then in my site.scss file I have it imported.

```
@import "scss/_custom-variables.scss";
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.scss";
@import "scss/_my-theme.scss";
```

When I look at my compiled CSS file I can see that the $blue is set to the correct value.

```
:root {
  --blue: #0078D2;
  --indigo: #6610f2;
  --purple: #6f42c1;
```

However, when I used the following for a table header it shows the default BS4 blue which is much lighter than the blue I'm looking to set. Here is a snippet of the comipiled CSS and you can see the blue is set correctly.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr class="table-primary">
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>File Date</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

The weird thing is that I have some basic text that I'm using the `text-primary` class with and it is picking up the `$blue` color that I set. So, there must be something with the `table-primary` but I'm not seeing it. I looked at the `_tables.scss` in my Bootstrap folder but I don't see anything in there that looks like it would be setting it. When I search my entire solution for `table-primary` all I find is the class in the compiled CSS and not in any of the .scss files. The `table-primary` in the compiled CSS has the lighter blue color.

This is picking up the correct blue.

```
<span class="text-primary">@ViewBag.FolderPath</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table colouring classes **make the colours lighter by default**.

If you don't want this to happen, replace `table-primary` with **`bg-primary`**.

---

Sources:

- [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#contextual-classes)
- [Source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/8f7bd419935adfcd53c471a0202083464800619e/scss/_tables.scss#L98-L105)

Answer (score 2):

Yes this will happen too to background of alert-primary, list-group-item-primary too due to awesome function [theme-color-level](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.1.0/scss/_functions.scss#L80) found in [bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.1.0/scss/_functions.scss) at line 80 of Bootstrap 4 sass, that dynamically create a lighter or darker color based on Your color. 
In your case the class table-primary has been generated in 
[bootstrap/scss/_tables.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.1.0/scss/_tables.scss#L103) at line 95:

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
    @include table-row-variant($color, theme-color-level($color, -9));
}
```

And [table-row-variant](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.1.0/scss/mixins/_table-row.scss#L3) mixin found in [bootstrap\scss\mixins_table-row.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.1.0/scss/mixins/_table-row.scss) at line 3 which will take the darker or lighter new color and set it as a background color of .table-primary, .table-primary > th, or .table-primary > td elements.

The main advantage of this feature is to generate a dynamic background colors to alert, table, and list-group-item for yours. try to update `$blue` or `$primary` to `#598234` or add a new theme color in your custom `scss/_custom-variables.scss` file like this

```
$theme-colors: ("javatmp": #598234);
```

You will get something like this taken from article [Preparing Template for Bootstrap customization](https://www.javatmp.com/pages/preparing-template-for-bootstrap-customization):
[image]

The following article provides little information for `theme-color-level` function: 
[Anatomy Of Bootstrap And JavaTMP SASS Theme Styling](https://www.javatmp.com/pages/anatomy-of-bootstrap-and-javatmp-sass-theme-styling)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I didn't know about the functions BS is using to create classes so this definitely makes more sense now. I'm sure this explanation will also help others as well.